# How do i remove a row from the database from selected row in table? JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am trying to make an editable table in jsp. I want to include also a delete button, on the other hand when i click the delete button i want to remove the row and also to remove the entry in the database.

I am using jsp and MySQL on Liferay portlets.

Can you please help me?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: also when i click delete it has to go in action file .java which is going to complete the task. if its possible if not i can use pure jsp to program it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a link called "Delet entry" in front of each row in your JSP. This link will execute a Servlet py getting aparameter from the JSP. Something whcih will look like this:

```
<a href="/DeleteServlet?id=<%=your_id_row%>"Delete entry</a>
```

Then in your Servlet's doGet method
get the id param by `String id = request.getParameter("id");`
and then delete the row by an SQL query.

Comment: The thing is that i want to avoid the SQL statements because i build my database with service builder which create useful method like getUseerID() for example deleteUser by userID all kind of methods like that!

Comment: Ok, then use the deleteUserByUserId and then provide that id by means of Integer.parseInt(id)